# How can I get my params in QueryDict?

Tags: python, ajax, django

I use the ajax pass the data to views.py:

```
var params = {'nood_id':'f55dbe56-7fa8-4d13-8e1e-2dc67499b6ac'}
$.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url:'/api/nood_detail/',
    data:{'params':params},
    dataType:'json',
    success:success_func,
})
```

In the views.py, the `request.POST` is bellow:

```
<QueryDict: {u'params[nood_id]': [u'f55dbe56-7fa8-4d13-8e1e-2dc67499b6ac']}>
```

I can not use the request.POST.get("params") to get the param, nor can I get the `nood_id`.

How can I get my params in QueryDict?

Comment: When passing json data, check `request.body`, The data is passed in that variable. Load that string into json and work on it. Let me know if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks not like intended:

```
<QueryDict: {u'params[nood_id]': [u'f55dbe56-7fa8-4d13-8e1e-2dc67499b6ac']}>
```

especially not this part: `u'params[nood_id]'`. This means your error already happens on the javascript side => somehow your params object was stringified partially? I'm not sure what happenend, it looks fishy to me.

In your Django view, you should be able to use `request.POST.get('nood_id')` or however you want the structure - but your JS has to send it correctly.

Try to change the JS to:

```
var params = {'nood_id':'f55dbe56-7fa8-4d13-8e1e-2dc67499b6ac'}
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '/api/nood_detail/',
    data: params,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: success_func,
})
```